# What will it take for a "Third Party" to gain REAL traction at any level in the United States?

Tags: united-states, parties, third-party

I've been around long enough to be registered to and somewhat involved with a number of so-called "third party" efforts. These include the [Libertarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libertarian_Party), [Peace and Freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_and_Freedom_Party), [Green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Party_of_the_United_States) and my very favorite defunct effort the [Natural Law Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Law_Party_(United_States)). The Greens and Libertarians have been around for at least 30 years and have NEVER expanded beyond their base of die-hard supporters. What do you think it will take for a new political party to break through and actually gain traction at the municipal, state or national levels?

Comment: Are you referring to the US? You should specify that in the question so we know.

Comment: The speculative nature of this question makes it not constructive.  No one has a crystal ball and punditry is not good for SE.  Voting to close.  (As much as I personally would love to get into this)

Comment: This type of discussion-starter and debate isn't really the type of question that will work with Stack Exchange.

Comment: Closers: this Q. is not asking for predictions, it's an abstract Q. about our models of political sufficiency, a [*quantum satis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_satis); *i.e.* how much power and resources are required.

Comment: @agc You're not concerned that, since this has never happened in the modern era, answers to this question will be overly speculative and more concerned with trashing the "corrupt two-party system" than actually answering the question? I'm not arguing against reopening, but that's the concern that's keeping me from casting a reopen vote

Comment: @divibisan, Re *"trashing"*: well, the Q. doesn't contain presumptuous terms like *"corrupt"* or even *"two"*.  These concerns imputed to what the OP *didn't* write appear to be based more on commentator speculation.

Comment: @agc I'm not making any assumptions about the asker (who hasn't been on the site for 7 years), but on people who might come in to answer it (especially since this question, in my opinion, has good odds of becoming a Hot Network Question and attracting lots of outside attention). I was hoping you'd make an argument to convince me why these concerns are unfounded and the question should be reopened. If you don't want to do that, you're under no obligation to engage

Comment: @divibisan, We might differ as to where the burden of proof falls here.  IMHO, it should be up to the commentators speculating *bad things* to argue, (rather than just assert), that their speculations are probable.

Comment: @agc I really don't understand why you're arguing. There's no burden of proof here – anyone is free to vote however they want. As I said, I'm not arguing against reopening. Since you seemed to think the question should be reopened, I was hoping you'd have an argument for why it should be. Since you don't (or don't care to share it), I won't vote to reopen. No harm done. I don't know why you think this line of argument would convince me – but if you don't care about convincing me, why engage at all?

Comment: @divibisan, Re *"I really don't understand why you're arguing"*:  You *did* just now say [*"I was hoping you'd make an argument to convince me"*.](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/591/what-will-it-take-for-a-third-party-to-gain-real-traction-at-any-level-in-the?noredirect=1#comment169047_591)  But since no *good* reasons have been given for closing, the burden of proof remains with the closers.